# System of equations setup

Tags: python-2.7, differential-equations

This stems from beam equations. How do I extract and order constants in matrixes to solve a system of equations rather than doing so by hand?

If I start with the differential equation d<sup>4</sup> v / dx<sup>4</sup> = q. I integrate 4x, and obtain 4 (more) equations, and thus 4x constants/unknown. For example:
v(x) = q x<sup>4</sup> / 24 + c<sub>1</sub> x<sup>3</sup> / 6 + c<sub>2</sub> x<sup>2</sup> / 2 + c<sub>3</sub> x + c<sub>4</sub>

If I apply the boundary condition v(5) = 0 this equation becomes

v(5) = q × 5<sup>4</sup> / 24 + c<sub>1</sub> × 5<sup>3</sup> / 6 + c<sub>2</sub> × 5<sup>2</sup> / 2 + c<sub>3</sub> × 5 + c<sub>4</sub> = 0, or

c<sub>1</sub> × 5<sup>3</sup> / 6 + c<sub>2</sub> × 5<sup>2</sup> / 2 + c<sub>3</sub> × 5 + c<sub>4</sub> = -q × 5<sup>4</sup> / 24

Of course to solve for 4 coefficients the other 3 DEs are used with 3 more boundary conditions. I was wondering if any one knows how I could sort and extract the constants to built up the system of equations rather than doing so by hand.

Comment: If you're going to work with this particular system of ODEs, it is just computing the polynomial coefficients, which shouldn't be hard (recursively applying a simple rule).  For the general case, you probably need some CAS library like `sympy`.  Not sure if it could beat pencil-and-paper, though...